# A seemingly impossible to terminate process

Tags: windows-7, process, cmd.exe, privileges, avast

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. Avast simply does not want to be stopped. Even SYSTEM does not kill it. I'm using these tools to run CMD as SYSTEM: http://reboot.pro/files/file/237-runassystem-and-runfromtoken/

See the following screenshot:

[image]

I even run CMD from the process token, and it still does not want to be terminated. So, how can I kill the damn thing?

Comment: Are you trying to uninstall it?

Comment: No, it froze, and I just want to kill the processes. I could probably just reboot, but I'd rather just kill it (and know why it's not being terminated).

Comment: basically, you can't. It installs special driver with hooks to prevent malicious software from doing anything like this. As by-effect, this prevents *any* software from doing this. If it froze, reboot is your only option.

Comment: try the Terminators from ProcessHacker: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I ended up just having to reboot. I guess that driver really does its job.

Answer (score 0):

1. With the `Win+ R` combo summon `services.msc`.
2. Right click on the service `Avast Antivirus` and click `Stop`.
3. Before it stops, Avast will warn you that the service is being stopped. Only if you are confident that your computer is safe click the `Ok` button and the service should stop.

Comment: That was grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the Avast! anti-malware suite were functioning properly, you could simply right-click on the symbol in the tray, and from the *Avast shields control*, disable it temporarily or permanently.
2. If it is *not* working, reinstall Avast! (which should fix any issue) or completely uninstall it and use another AV. It is *not* good practice to run Windows without AV.

Comment: I would have done that, but it was completely unresponsive.

Comment: Unresponsive PC (locked up)? Or "unresponsive" to attempt sat **reinstallation**? You do not need to stop Avast! to reinstall it.